# Class extends Application - can you get the reason for starting

Tags: android, android-intent, app-startup

If you have a class that `extends Application` it will be started/loaded i.e. `onCreate()` called if:

- Your app is opened by a user
- An exported service you declare in your manifest is ran (plugin)
- An exported Broadcast receiver is triggered
- A widget is added to the home screen
- Other reasons

When you're in an `Activity` you can get the calling `Intent`. I was wondering what you can do in the `Application` class to give some clue as to the intention of the starting scenario?

This is because I do a network operation if the application is starting, but I don't want to do it in these other scenarios. (*analytics for instance*).
If there isn't a way to get some information in the `Application` then yes I will consider moving the network operation to the default launcher activity.

Comment: Other than maybe `Binder.getCallingUid()` and kin, I'm not aware of anything you can get here.

Comment: Thanks I looked through those 3 `getCallingPid()` seemed to give different process ID's each time, but no way to correlate them. I could query for a running Activity but that's prone to error and requires a permission.

Comment: If the context in which the application is launched is important, then I'd argue that the network operation is not directly related to the application being created and so should not be placed in its `onCreate`. Trigger it explicitly from the scenarios that you desire.